# Does this site include the literary arts or music?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

This site is an arts and crafts beta. Does this include language arts? Poetry, short stories, novels and such? If not, where should I go for that?

Does music count as an art here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not cover *all* arts (performing, written, musical, etc.), only visual art and crafting.

---

For language arts (poetry, short stories, novels), your best bet is likely [Writers.SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/). They are also currently in beta, but would be able to address questions about written "art".

Music also does not count as an art for A&C, but either [Music: Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/) or [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) should be able to cover music questions.

Comment: Some background about naming this site — http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/20/will-google-show-this-site-in-its-top-results-if-someone-searches-for-drawing/23#23

Comment: There's also [Literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=pG-ejQRSCH0RMbN3ps5MrA2) for language arts - it hasn't reached beta stage yet, but I'm hoping it's close.