# Can I ask what platforms I can share my artworks on?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I've been tempted to ask this question but I don't think it's on-topic: What source/media is reliable to share my art with, like deviant art, etc. Would this question be on-topic? Or should I just not ask it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, that would be off-topic per [our Help page on allowed topics](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).**
(It would fall under service recommendations, and does not have a direct practical purpose. It's also quite broad, since, as it stands, no additional parameters are given.)

However, we have several questions here on Arts & Crafts Meta that are used to gather resources. These can be linked to in case users ask about them.

Examples include:

- [Anatomy and reference images](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/429/anatomy-and-reference-images)
- [Identify-this-painting questions](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/identify-this-painting-questions)

I've created [a thread here on Meta to serve the same purpose](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/438/) for (questions on) finding platforms for sharing works of art and crafted items.